# Prototype depending on global variable (what if that variable changes)

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototype

I'm building a JS prototype function and one of the values it uses is based on a global object named 'viewport'. However, if the values of this object will change; the prototype's values will not be accurate anymore.

What is the best or most efficient way to make sure the values are always equal?

**Getting the viewport values:**

```
  var viewport = {
     width: undefined
  }

  function initViewport($window){
     viewport.width = $window.width();
  }

  $(document).ready(function(){
     initViewport($(window));
  });

  $(window).resize(function(){
     initViewport($(window));
  });
```

**Creating the prototype:**

```
  // Slider it's width is depending the viewport width
  function Slider(){
     this.width = viewport.width;
  }

  Slider.prototype.slide = function(){
     console.log(this.width);
  }

  var slider = new Slider();
  slider.slide();
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a callback like this:

```
  var viewport = {
     width: undefined,
     onChange: []
  }

  function initViewport($window){
     viewport.width = $window.width();
     viewport.onChange.forEach(function(fn) {
         fn(viewport.width);
     });
  }
```

and in your slider:

```
  function Slider(){
     this.width = viewport.width;
     viewport.onChange.push(function(newvalue) {
         this.width = newvalue;
     }.bind(this));
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am afraid it returns 'undefined', I am not sure why.